# Merging two ASP.NET membership databases

Tags: asp.net, sql, membership

I have to merge two ASP.NET membership databases with related role and profile tables. Both databases have an identical role and profile structure. They use the built in providers (SqlMembershipProvider and friends). Duplicates are possible.

Do you have recommendations for me? Is there a tool to do this? If not: Can you recommend using the membership API or is it easier to use SQL.

**Update**

Here is the script I finally used to transfer the membership data.

```
insert into targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users
select * from sourceMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users
where username not in (select username from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users)

insert into targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_membership
select * from sourceMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_membership
where userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users)
and not userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_membership)

insert into targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_profile
select * from sourceMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_profile
where userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users)
and not userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_profile)

insert into targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_usersinroles
select * from sourceMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_usersinroles
where userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_users)
and not userid in (select userid from targetMembershipDatabase.dbo.aspnet_usersinroles)
```

Provided as is. No check for duplicate emails. No warranty that this is working in a more complex scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not aware of any tool which will do this, but the schema is pretty simple so it would be a straightforward enough job to just do it in SQL. All the keys are GUID anyway, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Obviously you'd need to check the user_name field for duplicates and email addresses, if the unique email address rule is applied. But if the roles are the same in both databases then all you're really interested in are the users. Once you've got them over it would just be a case of updating the `RoleId` and `ApplicationId` in `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_UsersInRoles`.

Comment: It was as easy as you said. No need for a tool beyond a simple T-SQL script :-)

Comment: @Dirk can you provide such T-SQL Script ?

Comment: @Dirk Thanks a  lot it is saving my lots of hours. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I am currently use a single database for three different applications. Each of them has its own `ApplicationID` and nothing special happend for me withing this 2 years. even similar mails are available (because sql check the `ApplicationID` and in each application only you have one mail) so I don't think that you have to consider something special

Just create a script from data and run in your mainDatabase just not that don't replace the schema of Tables.